# Is there Chinese and Japanese audio translation of Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-translation

Salam.

I am developing an Android application (that's full free for any body in any country, and we publish it on Google play market to download) for Quran that need audio translation of Chinese and Japanese languages.

I check http://voiceofquran.info/chinese_quran_translation.html but some files of theme not read and not exists or file was damaged!

Also I search internet for Japanese audio translation very much but no result found :(

Who can help me?!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is working but the quality seems low:

[chinese](https://archive.org/details/quran-translation-china)

japanese [surat al-baqara](https://archive.org/details/QuranJapanese002AlBaqarah1274Mp3) (2:1-274) [al-fatiha](https://archive.org/details/QuranJapanese001AlFaatihahMp3_275)
see also

http://www.videoquran.net/

http://www.islamicbulletin.org/services/foreign.htm

Comment: Salam.
Thanks for your reply, about your __chinese__ link, we need verse by verse files of each surah, but these files are surah by surah, that we are not understand chinese language and can't split file to verse by verse files! (can you help us for this problem?)
 Your __japanese__ link is for surah 2 and not complete file that we see it within our searches, and it isn't useful.
I visited both last links that could not help us! :(

Comment: hm... well i think you might find in the first two pages something as i don't understand neither Japanese nor Chinese I'd recommend you to search there!